# PHP perfect round off

Tags: php, math

I'm trying to round off following figures:

```
Case 1:
round( ((4/6) * 100), 2 ) . '%'; = 66.67%
round( ((1/6) * 100), 2 ) . '%'; = 16.67%
round( ((1/6) * 100), 2 ) . '%'; = 16.67%

Total % = 66.67 + 16.67 + 16.67 = 100.01%


Case 2:
round( ((5/11) * 100), 2 ) . '%'; = 45.45%
round( ((3/11) * 100), 2 ) . '%'; = 27.27%
round( ((3/11) * 100), 2 ) . '%'; = 27.27%

Total % = 45.45 + 27.27 + 27.27 = 99.99%
```

Can anyone tell me how would I make it perfect 100%

Thanks

Comment: Don't round the numbers early on `round( ((4/6) * 100), 2 ) . '%';` - this is taking away the precision you need to get back to 100%. Instead, simply run the numbers through`number_format` when you display them

Comment: What do you actually want the behaviour to be in the first case? Should the final number (16.67) be reduced to 16.66? Fundamentally, you can't sum numbers that you've rounded up and expect them to keep the same total.

Comment: The easiest way is to compute the last percentage as the difference between `100%` and the sum of the other percentages.

Answer (score 1):

If a prefect `100` is `100.00`, use this case:

```
round( ((4/6) * 100), 3 ); = 66.667
round( ((1/6) * 100), 3 ); = 16.667
round( ((1/6) * 100), 3 ); = 16.667
round(66.667+16.667+16.667, 2); = 100

echo round( ((5/11) * 100), 3 ); = 45.455
echo round( ((3/11) * 100), 3 ); = 27.273
echo round( ((3/11) * 100), 3 ); = 27.273
echo round(45.455+27.273+27.273, 2); = 100
```

You can make it more prefect by increasing rounded precision, e.g. use 15 instead of 3 for double values ;).
or

```
$a1 = (4/6)*100;
$b1 = (1/6)*100;
$c1 = (1/6)*100;
round($a1, 2);
round($b1, 2);
round($c1, 2);
round($a1+$b1+$c1, 2);

$a2 = (5/11)*100;
$b2 = (3/11)*100;
$c2 = (3/11)*100;
round($a2, 2);
round($b2, 2);
round($c2, 2);
round($a2+$b2+$c2, 2);
```

[`[PHP Demo]`](https://ideone.com/nom3Ri)

Comment: i want each percentage and rounded precision 2 only. And count of all percentage is 100.00%

Comment: You can only calculate the last value 100 - 66.67% - 16.67%. There is no other way if you want the same precision in your result